# How can you find the integral of $\frac{cos(2t)}{2t^2}$ between 1 and infinity?

Tags: integration, limits, trigonometry

How can you find the integral of $\frac{\cos(2t)}{2t^2}$
between 1 and infinity?
$$
I = \int\limits_1^\infty \frac{\cos(2t)}{2t^2} dt
$$

My problem is that I just simply do not know how to handle this. I have tried integration by parts and some trigonometric identities...

Comment: I think you can get a reasonable approximation if you use the series expansion for $cos2t$. (Integrals of the form $cosx/x$ are non integrable, but this integral can be represented by a special function $Ci(x)$. Maybe this link will help? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html )

Comment: There's no elementary solution; Wolfram's solution involves the sine integral $Si$ (which can be recast through integration by parts into the cosine integral $Ci$, as has already been mentioned). You can get an approximation by noting that $|\cos(2t)| \leq 1$ and $\int_M^\infty \frac{1}{2t^2} = \frac{1}{2M}$. Now given $\varepsilon>0$ you can choose $M$ so that $1/2M < \varepsilon/2$, and then choose $N$ so that the $N$th Maclaurin polynomial of $\cos(2t)$ is within $\varepsilon/2M$ of $\cos(2t)$ on $[1,M]$. Then the problem is just to integrate $\frac{1}{2t^2}$ plus a polynomial.

Comment: Here is the [WA link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+1+to+infinity+cos%282*t%29%2F%282*t^2%29+dt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the actual integration of $\cos(2t)/(2t^2)$ would be difficult to find explicitly, you can show that the integral converges by noting $$|I| \le \int_1^\infty \frac{|\cos(2t)|}{2t^2} dt \le \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{2t^2} dt < \infty.$$ The last integral can be integrated by standard techniques. Also we know that it converges by the $p$-test.

As for computing the value of the integral, one method that is typically used to compute improper integrals is to transform the integral to an integral over a finite interval. We can achieve this with the substitution $u=1/t$ which makes $du = -1/t^{2} dt$. Thus we have $$\int_{1}^\infty \frac{\cos(2t)}{2t^2} dt = \int_{0}^1 \frac{\cos(2/u)}{2} du.$$

This wont be any easier to find an antiderivative for, however, it will make it easier to approximate the integral. One way would be to use a Riemann sum on the interval $[0,1]$.